# Rails collection_select and Foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, grouped-collection-select

Following is my code,

```
<%= f.collection_select :event_member_id, EventMember.all, :id, :company_member_id, :prompt => "Please select" %>
```

Here `:company_member_id` is foreign_key in `EventMember` class, i wanted to display text_method as company_member_email instead of company_member_id,

So my collection_select should be like below,

```
<%= f.collection_select :event_member_id, EventMember.all, :id, :'company_member.email', :prompt => "Please select" %>
```

How to achieve above...!!!

Comment: Did you tried giving like this `<%= f.collection_select :event_member_id, EventMember.all, :id,:company_member_email, :prompt => "Please select" %>`?

Comment: Yes but giving error as undefined method `company_member_email' for #<EventMember:0xb43bb078>

Comment: In which table do you have this field `company_member_email`?

Comment: I have email in ComanyMember class, not in EventMember..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `EventMember` modal :-

```
def company_member_email
  return self.company_member.email unless self.company_member.nil?
  ""
end
```

And the collection as:-

```
<%= f.collection_select :event_member_id, EventMember.all, :id, :company_member_email, :prompt => "Please select" %>
```

Comment: Nice it saved my time, Is this right approach to call foreign key values in collection_select!!!